# Powershell: creating dynamic forms

Tags: forms, powershell, dynamic

I try to create a dynamic form with buttons which have directory names. Clicking in the button should take the directory name and process it.

code sinpped:

```
{function convert_it($arg)

    $dir = "$source\$arg"
    $dir_liste =  Get-ChildItem $dir | Where-Object {$_.mode -match "d"} 
    $dir_count_total = $dir_liste.count

...

...

...

}



foreach ($dir in $dir_list)

{   
# Button
if ($split_count -eq 25){
    $x=250
    $y=50
}
elseif ($split_count -eq 50){
    $x=500
    $y=50
}

$dir_numbers = (get-childitem -Path $source\$dir -recurse | where-object { 
$_.PSIsContainer }).Count

$run = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$run.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($x,$y)
$run.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
if ($dir_numbers -eq 0) {
    $run.Enabled = $false
}
$run.Text = "#$dir_count -> $dir -> $dir_numbers"

$run.Add_Click({ convert_it($dir) }.GetNewClosure())

$testForm.Controls.Add($run)
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman",14,
[System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$run.font = $Font
$run.AutoSize = $True
$y+=30
$split_count+=1
$dir_count+=1

}







$testForm.ShowDialog()
```

When I run the script, I get the following error:

convert_it : The term 'convert_it' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

- $run.Add_Click({ convert_it($dir) }.GetNewClosure())
- ~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (convert_it:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

What do I wrong here?:

```
$run.Add_Click({ convert_it $dir }.GetNewClosure())
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the opening bracket in the wrong location for your function (should be at the end of the line instead of at the beginning (this makes it a scriptblock instead).

Should be this:

```
function convert_it($arg) {

    $dir = "$source\$arg"
    $dir_liste =  Get-ChildItem $dir | Where-Object {$_.mode -match "d"} 
    $dir_count_total = $dir_liste.count
    ...
}
```